# Assigning array values in new array giving error

Tags: javascript, arrays

Trying to assign array values in new array is giving error. Can someone help out why is it giving error?

```html
<html>
<head>
 <style>
  
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <script>
 var a=["red","yellow","pink","blue","aqua"];
 var b=["rose","lotus","sunflower","lily","mogra"];
 var c=["mango","banana","orange","blueberry","lichi"];
 console.log(a[1]);
 console.log(b[2]);
 console.log(c[3]);
 var d=[a[l],b[2],c[3]];
 console.log(d);
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `l` is not the same as `1`. Use a better font in your editor to clearly see the difference.

Comment: you have l instead of 1, is this a  typo?

Comment: `var d=[a[l],b[2],c[3]];` => `var d=[a[1],b[2],c[3]];`

Comment: Yes, was a typo error sorry. My mistake, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote an 'l' instead of a '1' on this line:

var d=[a[l],b[2],c[3]];

Fixed below:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <style>
  
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <script>
 var a=["red","yellow","pink","blue","aqua"];
 var b=["rose","lotus","sunflower","lily","mogra"];
 var c=["mango","banana","orange","blueberry","lichi"];
 console.log(a[1]);
 console.log(b[2]);
 console.log(c[3]);
 var d=[a[1],b[2],c[3]];
 console.log(d);
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```